# How to use AngularJS to build javascript widgets for public use?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, widget

I'm trying to build a JavaScript widget that will allow webmasters to just cut and paste a few lines of code to display some functionality and UI on their site.

I've seen a good example of doing this kind of thing in JQuery, but not Angular. I'm assuming the widget will need to download the angularjs javascript file conditionally (based on whether it has already been loaded).

Has anyone had experience doing this in Angular and can recommend whether or not to do it in Angular or just stick with jQuery?

e.g. FourSquare's widget code:

Save to foursquare

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
   window.___fourSq = {"uid":"606"};
   var s = document.createElement('script');
   s.type = 'text/javascript';
   s.src = 'http://platform.foursquare.com/js/widgets.js';
   s.async = true;
   var ph = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   ph.parentNode.insertBefore(s, ph);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, even in jQuery you need to download the src if not present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe AngularJS is a framework with is targetted towards Single Page Apps (SPA) and provides all the infrastructure around it. The use of widget within existing HTML pages is not a ideal use case for using AngularJS.

jQuery is more of a utility belt \ library and hence can be used anywhere.

Comment: Not happy as I've really grown to like angular, but that's the advice I was looking for. Thanks!