# is angularjs still frowned upon to build widgets that installs on 3rd party websites when compared to jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I read a stackoverflow post stating that using jquery to build a widget is better than angularjs. Their reasoning was because angularjs widget might interfere with the angularjs installed on the websites browser.

Link to the post: [How to use AngularJS to build javascript widgets for public use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778408/how-to-use-angularjs-to-build-javascript-widgets-for-public-use)

It was posted in 2013, so I'm not sure if angularjs was updated to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the applications are all using Angular then Angular widgets are the best asbthey give you more power and tie into the framework itaelf naturally.

If you are talking about general widgets then you want as few dependencies as possible. If you create a an Angular widget is will not be usable without Angular and people using other frameworks will not accept pulling in Angular to use your widget.

Comment: Wait now i'm confused. Because the user will be installing a widget that's pulling data from MY server to populate what they see. And the widget just installs using a single line of js, that's located on my serever.

Comment: But to be able to execute that code they will nees to also load in all dependencies in addition to the code of the widget.

Comment: And with Jquery, it doesn't require any dependencies?

Comment: That is still a dependency. The users of your component will still need to load in the same version of JQuery you built your widget for.

Comment: If you're installing a widget 

EXAMPLE: <script src="//load.sumome.com/" data-sumo-site-id="55159cb377b4a21436f376b3c9b3bad99cda91dc675158886aea620fda69624c" async="async"></script> . 

Wouldn't the load.sumome.com code include all the dependencies required to load their widget? If both require dependencies, than I don't see why angularjs is worse compared to jquery (unless jquery has less dependencies).

Comment: For development of a web application it is a standard practice to bundle together all dependencies into a single file and minify it. However it is very bad practice to bundle all dependencies into a single file when you are only delivering a small piece of the entire application. The issue being a version clash in dependencies. For example the site loads in version 1.x and you are bundling version 2.x, since these versions do not match and only one version with be loaded. Breaking either your widget your the entire site that loaded your widget.

Comment: Ah that makes, multiple versions will conflict. So since you developed in both angluarjs and jquery, which one would you recommend to build a widget that will install in other websites?

Comment: If you are trying to provide this feature to sites you have no control over and do not want to force them to use your dependency versions then you have 2 choices. No dependencies at all. Or have them loan your content via an iframe, although they would not be able to style the components.